# Team Fortress 2 randomly crashes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, crash, gaming, steam

While playing Team Fortress 2 on my Windows 10 laptop, it happens that the game randomly crashes without any message. This problem never occurred until it showed up some months ago and now it happens almost every time I play.

I read that a possible solution is to delete some folders (cfg, media, sound) but it did not work in my case. I have no mods installed, just the game  as you install it. How can I identify the problem?

Comment: Check the event log and paste it here. `Right click the windows start button in bottom left > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application` Find the error where your game crashed and paste the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem by [verifying the integrity of game files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335&l=english).